# Create .nfo-files recursively

Tags: find, directory

I have a collection of concert-media (audio and video). They're all organised using the same pattern:

`./ARTISTNAME/[YYYY-MM-DD] VENUE, CITY`

Basically I want to write a script which goes through the folders, looks for the [YYYY-MM-DD]-folders and get the information regarding artist (one folder level above), date, venue and location (using the name of the folder it just found) and writing the information into a .nfo-file which it saves into the found folder.

I already did quite a research on this topic, found a similar script but I am stuck because it searches files instead of folders:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -path "*[????-??-??]*" | while read folder; do # the script is supposed to look for the concert-folders
      ->  band_name=`echo $file_name | sed 's/ *-.*$//'` # Get rid of song name
      ->  band_name=`echo $band_name | sed 's/^.*\///'`  # Get rid of file path
      ->  song_name=`echo $file_name | sed 's/^.*- *//'` # Get rid of band name
      ->  song_name=`echo $song_name | sed 's/.avi//'` # Get rid of file extension
      ->  new_file_name=`echo $file_name | sed 's/.avi/.nfo/'` # Make new filename
      ->  echo "Making $new_file_name..."
        echo -en "<musicvideo>\n<venue>$venue_name</venue>\n<city>$city_name</city><date>$date>\date>\n<artist>$band_name</artist>\n</musicvideo>\n" > "$new_file_name"
done
```

After changing the first part of the script (making it look for the folders with "[YYYY-MM-DD]") I understand that the second part of the script allocates the "tags" (such as artist, date, location, etc.). But I don't know how to make the script take the tags from folder names. Basically help is needed after the "->".

At the last part of the script it is supposed to write the collected information for this folder into a .nfo-file (e.g. FOLDERNAME.nfo).

Comment: Is there a reason you are restricting yourself to bash? This would be easier to implement in something like Perl or Python.

Comment: The reason is me not having any knowledge about Perl or Python.

Comment: So a path will look like this "./THE WHO/1969-08-17 Woodstock, Woodstock". With spaces in the paths?

Comment: Not exactly. It will look like this "./THE WHO/[1969-08-17] Woodstock, Woodstock". Yes, with spaces.

Comment: Where does the nfo file end up? Under "THE WHO" or "THE WHO/[1969-08-17] Woodstock, Woodstock"? What exactly would the file name be?

Comment: The nfo-file for this special concert would end up in the folder "THE WHO/[1969-08-17] Woodstock, Woodstock". For every concert there should be a seperate nfo-file in the "concert"-folder with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple Python example to get you started. If you want to port it to shell you can.

First, my setup:

```
test
test/BOB
test/BOB/[3011-01-01] Lollapalooza 213, Saturn Base 5
test/THE WHO
test/THE WHO/[1969-08-17] Woodstock, Woodstock
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import os.path
import re
import sys


def handle_concert(dirname, artist, date, venue, city):
    """Create a NFO file in the directory."""

    # the {} are replaced by each argument in turn, like printf()
    # Using a triple quote is a lot like a here document in shell, i.e.
    # cat <EOF
    # foo
    # EOF
    nfo_data = """<musicvideo>
<venue>{}</venue>
<city>{}</city>
<date>{}</date>
<artist>{}</artist>
</musicvideo>
""".format(venue, city, date, artist)

    nfo_file = "[{}] {}, {}.nfo".format(date, venue, city)

    # when the with statement is done the file is closed and fully
    # written.
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, nfo_file), "w") as fp:
        fp.write(nfo_data)


# This is a regular expression which matches:
# */FOO/[YYYY-MM-DD] VENUE, CITY
# Where possible, white space is left intact
concert_re = re.compile(r'.*/(?P<artist>.+)/\[(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\]\s+(?P<venue>.+),\s+(?P<city>.+)')

def handle_artist(dirname):
    """Found an ARTIST directory. Look for concerts.
    If a subdirectory is found, see if it matches a concert.
    When a concert is found, handle it.
    """
    for i in os.listdir(dirname):
        subdir = os.path.join(dirname, i)
        m = concert_re.match(subdir)
        if m:
            print subdir  # to watch the progress
            handle_concert(subdir, m.group("artist"), m.group("date"),
                           m.group("venue"), m.group("city"))


def walk_collection(start_dir):
    """Examine contents of start_dir.
    If a directory is found, assume it is an ARTIST.
    """
    for i in os.listdir(start_dir):
        # os.path.join ensures paths are right regardless of OS
        dirname = os.path.join(start_dir, i)
        if os.path.isdir(dirname):
            print dirname  # to watch the progress
            handle_artist(dirname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    collection_dir = sys.argv[1]  # equiv of $1

    walk_collection(collection_dir)
```

How to run it:

```
$ nfo-creator.py /path/to/your/collection
```

The results:

```
<musicvideo>
<venue>Woodstock</venue>
<city>Woodstock</city>
<date>1969-08-17</date>
<artist>THE WHO</artist>
</musicvideo>
```

and

```
<musicvideo>
<venue>Lollapalooza 213</venue>
<city>Saturn Base 5</city>
<date>3011-01-01</date>
<artist>BOB</artist>
</musicvideo>
```

You can add more `handle_` functions to handle differing formats. Just define a new regular expression and a handler for it. I kept this really simple for learning purposes with plenty of shell oriented comments.

This could totally be done in the shell. But writing this Python code was way easier and allows for more growth in the future.

Enjoy, and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Awesome start you gave me there. But executing the script leads to the following error:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "nfo-creator.py", line 64, in <module>
>    collection_dir = sys.argv[1]  # equiv of $1
>IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Let me update with an example. Basically it is complaining because you did not tell it where to look for files.

Comment: I kept it really simple so you could follow along. In real code I would replace ``sys.argv`` and use the Python ``argparse`` module instead. This handles standard ``--foo -b 5`` style command line parameters. Overkill for this example but it gives you ``--help`` for free and better errors when you omit an argument.

Comment: You keeping it simple is really appreciated. I will use it and try to understand the parts so I'll be able to extend it myself someday.

Any chance the nfo could be named after the direction? In this example "[1969-08-17] Woodstock, Woodstock.nfo"?

I tried to mess with your line 
`with open(os.path.join(dirname, ".nfo"), "w") as fp:
        fp.write(nfo_data)` 
and tried something like (dirname).nfo and similar things. But no argument would give the actual direction's name.

Comment: You hadn't answered when I asked what the filename would be so I left it as a learning exercise. I will update the code so you can see what the change looks like.